# Is it more efficient to do multiple database counts or count in code with Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a django model and each entry in the table has a type ID. I need to get a count for each type.

Given this line in the documentation:

> A count() call performs a SELECT COUNT(*) behind the scenes, so you should always use count() rather than loading all of the record into Python objects and calling len() on the result

Is it more efficient to get every object and count each type programmatically or do a database .count() for each type? I am using a postgresql database.

Comment: If you need a count for each id it is more efficient to write a query which does that. So both mentioned methods are less efficient than writing this extra query.

Comment: You can start by thinking about how many layers of abstractions are involved with any given query: a `select *` will result in every row being sent to the program requiring the usual creation of objects outside of the database process, whereas a `select count(*)` keeps everything inside the database process despite the possibility of having to go through every row of data, saving the time it takes to move data to your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use aggregation, e.g. `MyModel.objects.values('type_id').annotate(Count('type_id'))`

This does a sensible query, not something that's going to  "get every object and count each type" which would be way too much work!

More about this here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet